# What is language of repeat(L) = {ww | w ∊ L}?

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions, context-sensitive

> What is language of repeat(L) = {ww | w ∊ L} ?

---

#### My try:

I know it {ww | w ∊ (a,b)*} is context sensitive language. Here , what is meant by "repeat(L)" ?  Can you explain it ? It is not a homework question.

Comment: The notation "repeat(L)" is defined in your question.

Comment: It's hard to tell from your question what your particular confusion is.  I suggest that you edit the question to explain what you don't understand.  You already wrote a definition of repeat(L); what about it is confusing?  Do you know what the notation means?  What are your thoughts -- if you had to guess what it means, what would your guess be?  What possible meanings have you considered?  What self-study have you done?  You can find more tips about how to ask a good question here: http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$repeat(\cdot)$ is an operator on languages. It takes as an input a language $L$, and outputs a language defined by $\{ xx \mid x \in L\}$. That is, for any word $x\in L$ the string $xx$ will be in the output language $repeat(L)$.

A Few examples:

> $L=\{ 0,00, 11\}$  =>  $repeat(L) = \{ 00,0000,1111\}$
>
> $L=\{ \}$   => $repeat(L) = \{ \}$
>
> $L=\Sigma^*=\{\epsilon,0,1,00,01,10,11,...\}$ => $repeat(L)= \{\epsilon, 00,11,0000,0101,1010,1111,...\}$