# Language of words concatenated with themselves

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, context-free

Let $L$ be a regular language.

Is the language $L_2 = \{ ww | w \in L \}$  context-free? Does it have a name?

Comment: Not regular, not even when $L=\{a,b\}^*$. See for example https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/11759, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/38459/4287 or https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/45681/4287 .

Comment: @HendrikJan thanks, see my edit, I'm also interested in the name of the language

Comment: OK, I should have added the language for $L=\{a,b\}^*$ is not context-free. Usually one of the standard examples for which the pumping lemma for context-free languages is applied. I do not know of a well-established name. The last question I linked to uses "repeat(L)".